# jqxGrid enable & disable cells edit by dropdown

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid, jqwidget

```js
var rowEdit = function (row) {
    if (row == 0)
        return True;
}
```

I have jqxGrid with 6 Columns (Unique Number,Verified "Yes or No",Tracking Number,Serial Number,Condition,Remarks)

Verified "Yes or No" is a dropdownlist.

problem: base on column "Verified" i want to enable or disable the other fields. for example if "YES" enable for editing else if "NO" disable  (no edits allowed)

please assist.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Hi, i have shared my code.

Comment: You have to add your cade as an edit of your question, not as an answer.

Comment: I have edited my post, sorry for that.

Comment: Try to look at `cellbeginedit` function in the `columns` property. You define it on each columns. And then, inside the function, you check the value of the `Verified` column and return `false` to disable edition and `true`to enable edition.

Comment: Hi  ADreNaLiNe-DJ, I have tried that it doesn't work

Comment: I've used this functionality several times, so there's something in your cade that makes it "crash". Can you create a JSFiddle with your code ?

Comment: unfortunately i can not create  JSFiddle because i am using other function from other application, JSFiddle can not run in this instance.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ can you maybe cellbeginedit function on one of my column since you are saying you have used this function serveral times, just to see if i was doing it correctly. please. thank you for quick replies  .....Much appreciated

Comment: Can you post the `rowEdit` function please ?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ i have uptadeted the post, my " rowEdit" is just enabling the editable only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `cellbeginedit` function in the `columns` property, you can define which column is editable or not.

You have to define it on each column and inside the function, you check the value of the `Verified` column to determine if the column is editable (`return true`) or not (`return false`).

The function takes 3 arguments

1. The row index: which can be used to get all the row data (function `getrowdata` of the grid).
2. The datafield: the one you've defined in the `columns` property.
3. The column type.

So, your `rowEdit` function should look like this:

```
var rowEdit = function (rowindex, datafield, columntype) {
    if(datafield != "Verified"){
        var rowdata = $("#itemGrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', rowindex);
        return rowdata.Verified == "YES";
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've used the value `YES` for the `Verified` column, because I ingore which is the correct value for this data.

But, you can replace with the good one.

Comment: Thank you. but that is still allowing edit either way if it is "YES" or "NO", i dont know if i am missing something else......Thank you.

Comment: You should try to make a JSFidlle with sample data

Comment: thank you I will try to do that tomorrow morning.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you ADreNaLiNe-DJ, it is now working, i was awya on holiday i just tested the solution now again and it is working.